# findAll() is not a function in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Express.js with sequelize
I am trying to get data from table but findALL() method not working

Here , I am sharing my models & controller file

**checkout_product model**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Checkout_product = sequelize.define(
        "Checkout_products",
        {
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            ptice: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            image: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            quantity: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            },
        },
    );

   Checkout_product.associate = function (models) {
        Checkout_product.hasMany(models.Product_attribute, {
            foreignKey: "product_id",
            sourceKey: "id"
        });
    };

    return Checkout_product;
};
```

**product_attribute model**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Product_attribute = sequelize.define(
        "product_attributes",
       {
            product_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            },
            attribute_name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            attribute: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            price: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
        },
    );

     Product_attribute.associate = (models) => {
        Product_attribute.belongsTo(models.Checkout_product, {
            foreignKey: "product_id",
            sourceKey: "id"
        });
    };

    return Product_attribute;
};
```

**models/index.js file**

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const config = require("./../config/development").database;

let sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  config
);
let db = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== "index.js";
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    let model = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**Controller**

```
const Checkout_product  = require('../models');

module.exports.checkout_product_get = function (req, res) {
  Checkout_product.findAll({
     include: [ {
       model : Product_attributes,
     }]
  })
  .then(checkout_product => {
        res.json(checkout_product)
  })
}
```

I am stuck to get data from checkout_product  & it's child model product_attribute model,
Everytime I am getting same error : **TypeError: Checkout_product.findAll is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

const Checkout_product  = require('../models').table_name;
Can you try it

Answer (score -1):

You are using the deprecated - legacy way of Sequelize to initialize models. Newer ways with `require` and `extends` are available and suggested. Check the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/index.html) for more information.

Regarding your code....

You are neither initializing the db structure properly nor using it correctly later...

First your code here in `index.js`:

```js
 .forEach(function(file) {
    let model = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

Just loads the model files in the `db` object. But these files are functions ment to be called with sequelize object as parameter. This is done by providing them to `sequelize.import` that manages the proper call of the defined model-functions to create the model instances. Check https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html

Also after successfully initializing the db, in your controller code, the `require('../models')` returns the total `db` object. So if you want to use a specific model *as Checkout_product* in your case, you have to access it in the object:

```js
const db = require('../models');
db.Checkout_product.findAll()...
```

Comment: I updated index.js file with use of sequlize.import  method
`fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(function(file) {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
})
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });`

Now, I am getting this error : return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
ReferenceError: basename is not defined

Comment: I cannot understand your code snippet, basename is not initialized anywhere so it is correct to say undefined